# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /../plugins/rm-payment.php

Tags: plugins, wp-query

I using remote payment system of 2 WordPress site, 1st WordPress site to 2nd WordPress site. 1st is main website & 2nd website work like merchant website that process payment of paypal. We fetch user order details of 1st website to 2nd website for process paypal payment. But on fetching web page of 2nd website getting error, but remember it solved if reload it once

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array in /../plugins/rm-payment.php:on line 231

```
 $response = wp_remote_post( $remote_url, $request );

        if(strlen($response["body"]) > 0) {

            $insert = $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
                'user_email' => $query['user'], 
                'reference' => $query['ref'], 
                'token_ref' => $token_ref, 
                'point_type' => $query['ctype'],
                'amount' => $query['amount'], 
                'cost' => $total_price,
                'ref_id' => $timestamp,
                'payment_date' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                'created_at' => current_time( 'mysql' )
            ));

            $insert2 = $A_wpdb->insert( $A_table_name, array(
                'user_email' => $query['user'], 
                'reference' => $query['ref'], 
                'amount' => $query['amount'], 
                'ref_id' => $timestamp,
                'payment_date' => current_time( 'mysql' ),
                'created_at' => current_time( 'mysql' )
            ));

            if($insert) {
                $payment_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
            } else {
                echo "Error!"; exit();
            }
        } else {
            wp_redirect( $query['url'] . '?message=user-not-exist' ); exit();
        }
```

'''

Comment: In the given code, which line is 231? The provided error tells us that on line 231 we have a WP_Error Object instead of an array.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you're accessing `$response` as an array when it's a `\WP_Error`. Check out the [possible return values of `wp_remote_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_remote_post/#return):

> *(array|WP_Error)* The response or WP_Error on failure.

You should modify your code in a couple of ways:

```php
$response = wp_remote_post( $remote_url, $request );

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    // handle the error response here.
}

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );

if( false !== strlen( $body ) ) {
```

This ensures you catch any `\WP_Error` returns and gets the body data using `wp_remote_retrieve_body`. You can also use `wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response )` to get the HTTP status code (e.g. `200`, `401`, etc.)